# Pointer thread safety

Tags: pointers, thread-safety

I have 2 tasks who might call the below function (fun1) at the same time. Is this tread safe? Do we need to add lock in fun1 also?

```
char * my_malloc(int size)
{
   char *p;
   sem_lock(&l1); //locking
   p= malloc(size);
   sem_unlock(&l1);  //unlocking
   return p;
}

char * fun1(int size)
{
  char *ptr; 
  ptr = my_malloc(size);
  return ptr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as they use the same semaphore, it should be ok.

*I would have place the locking code in `fun1`and `fun2` for clarity (but it is personnal).*